# Chrome doesn't save DataTables state when clicking to go back

Tags: datatables

I have this [datatable](https://datatables.net/) below:

```
var table = $(who_show).DataTable({
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
                    "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'],
                    "data" : data,
                    "columns" : columns,
                    "paging": true,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "pageLength" : 10,
                    stateSave: true
                });
```

The code is working, many of these columns have links to access other pages but ***when i click to go back*** using **Google Chrome** i lose my state and need to do all filterings again. Firefox does it with no problems.

I hope it was clear. Any thoughts?

**Chrome Version:** 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)